# Number format exception being thrown while fetching a specific row from db

Tags: android, sqlite

Im fetching all records from a specific row of a db as follows,

```
  public StatutoryModel getStatutoryRow(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_KNOWLEDGE_STATUTORY, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                        KEY_STATUTORY_MAPPING, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_DESCRIPTION,KEY_ACTIVE,KEY_PROVISION,KEY_COMPLIANCE_TASK,KEY_FORMAT_FILE_LIST,KEY_DURATION,KEY_DOC_NAME,KEY_PENAL_CONSEQUENCE,KEY_DURATION_ID,KEY_FREQUENCY_ID,KEY_REPEAT_FREQ,KEY_COMPLIANCE_ID,KEY_REPEAT_TYPE_ID,KEY_STATUTORY_MONTH}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        StatutoryModel contact = new StatutoryModel(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8), cursor.getString(9), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(10)), cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(13)), cursor.getString(14), cursor.getString(15), cursor.getString(16), cursor.getString(17), cursor.getString(18), cursor.getString(19));
        // return contact
        return contact;
    }
```

And Im invoking it as follows,

```
Db.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getStatutoryRow(1).getDescription()
```

The issue is that im getting numberformatexception when Im trying to do so. Following is my error log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
 ComponentInfo{com.activities/com.activities.StatutoryDecision}:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
at com.Controllers.Db.getStatutoryRow(Db.java:292)
at com.activities.StatutoryDecision.onCreate(StatutoryDecision.java:44)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Following is my model class

```
public class StatutoryModel {
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private String isStatutoryActive;
    private String statutoryProvision;
    private String complianceTask;
    private String format_fileList;
    private String duration;
    private String document_name;
    private String penalConsequences;
    private String durationType_id;
    private int frequencyId;
    private String repeatsEvery;
    private int complianceId;
    private String repeatsTypeId;
    String statutory_month;
    private  String statutory_date;
    private String trigger_before_days;
    private String repeat_by;
    private String statuoryMapping;
    private String location;



    private static StatutoryModel ourInstance = new StatutoryModel();

    public static StatutoryModel getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    public StatutoryModel() {
    }

    public StatutoryModel(int id, String description, String isStatutoryActive, String statutoryProvision, String complianceTask, String format_fileList, String duration, String penalConsequences, String document_name, String durationType_id, int frequencyId, String repeatsEvery, String repeatsTypeId, int complianceId, String statutory_month, String statutory_date, String trigger_before_days, String repeat_by, String statuoryMapping, String location) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.isStatutoryActive = isStatutoryActive;
        this.statutoryProvision = statutoryProvision;
        this.complianceTask = complianceTask;
        this.format_fileList = format_fileList;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.penalConsequences = penalConsequences;
        this.document_name = document_name;
        this.durationType_id = durationType_id;
        this.frequencyId = frequencyId;
        this.repeatsEvery = repeatsEvery;
        this.repeatsTypeId = repeatsTypeId;
        this.complianceId = complianceId;
        this.statutory_month = statutory_month;
        this.statutory_date = statutory_date;
        this.trigger_before_days = trigger_before_days;
        this.repeat_by = repeat_by;
        this.statuoryMapping = statuoryMapping;
        this.location = location;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getIsStatutoryActive() {
        return isStatutoryActive;
    }

    public void setIsStatutoryActive(String isStatutoryActive) {
        this.isStatutoryActive = isStatutoryActive;
    }

    public String getComplianceTask() {
        return complianceTask;
    }

    public void setComplianceTask(String complianceTask) {
        this.complianceTask = complianceTask;
    }

    public String getStatutoryProvision() {
        return statutoryProvision;
    }

    public void setStatutoryProvision(String statutoryProvision) {
        this.statutoryProvision = statutoryProvision;
    }

    public String getFormat_fileList() {
        return format_fileList;
    }

    public void setFormat_fileList(String format_fileList) {
        this.format_fileList = format_fileList;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getDocument_name() {
        return document_name;
    }

    public void setDocument_name(String document_name) {
        this.document_name = document_name;
    }

    public String getPenalConsequences() {
        return penalConsequences;
    }

    public void setPenalConsequences(String penalConsequences) {
        this.penalConsequences = penalConsequences;
    }

    public String getDurationType_id() {
        return durationType_id;
    }

    public void setDurationType_id(String durationType_id) {
        this.durationType_id = durationType_id;
    }

    public int getFrequencyId() {
        return frequencyId;
    }

    public void setFrequencyId(int frequencyId) {
        this.frequencyId = frequencyId;
    }

    public String getRepeatsEvery() {
        return repeatsEvery;
    }

    public void setRepeatsEvery(String repeatsEvery) {
        this.repeatsEvery = repeatsEvery;
    }

    public int getComplianceId() {
        return complianceId;
    }

    public void setComplianceId(int complianceId) {
        this.complianceId = complianceId;
    }

    public String getRepeatsTypeId() {
        return repeatsTypeId;
    }

    public void setRepeatsTypeId(String repeatsTypeId) {
        this.repeatsTypeId = repeatsTypeId;
    }

    public String getStatutory_month() {
        return statutory_month;
    }

    public void setStatutory_month(String statutory_month) {
        this.statutory_month = statutory_month;
    }

    public String getStatutory_date() {
        return statutory_date;
    }

    public void setStatutory_date(String statutory_date) {
        this.statutory_date = statutory_date;
    }

    public String getRepeat_by() {
        return repeat_by;
    }

    public void setRepeat_by(String repeat_by) {
        this.repeat_by = repeat_by;
    }

    public String getTrigger_before_days() {
        return trigger_before_days;
    }

    public void setTrigger_before_days(String trigger_before_days) {
        this.trigger_before_days = trigger_before_days;
    }

    public String getStatuoryMapping() {
        return statuoryMapping;
    }

    public void setStatuoryMapping(String statuoryMapping) {
        this.statuoryMapping = statuoryMapping;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }


}
```

Comment: I think, your database have number datatype for KEY_ID. then you can use cursor.getInt(0) instead of Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

int cannot take "" or null values. "" is a string while you want an int. Hence, the numberformat error. Instead of int use Integer. Instead of passing "", pass null when using the method.

Comment: now it says `Couldn't read row 0, col 17 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it`

Comment: Column numbers start from 0 so see if you have total of 17 columns or 18. If 17 then column numbers should go from 0 to 16 and not 1 to 17. If my answer has solved the number formatexception mark it as correct

Comment: there are 20 columns in total

Comment: Your cursor has only 17 columns. Count again. Check your db.query

Comment: i tried doing like cursor.getColumnCount and it prints 20 as column count

Answer (score 1):

> `Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))`

This is invoking the exception. so `cursor.getString(0)` is not returning a number, perhaps because it is not stored in your database.

Comment: Im getting `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 17 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.`

Comment: See you are making an object of `StatutoryModel` class from the values that are coming from database. I request you to please post code of that class here so that i can see what data types you have used.

Comment: Ok i saw it. Revert all changes suggested by @suku answer. The first parameter is int and you are fetching the values from database and initialising it. The problem is not with your code but the values stored in database. See the Exception, it says `Invalid int: "" `. So it is not getting any value in the first place to convert it to int. So it is throwing you number format exception.

Comment: The ID column in the database is empty. It doesn't have any values. Did you get it?

Comment: now i dont get numberformatexception but `Couldn't read row 0, col 17 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it`

Comment: That means the table you have created in your database doesn't have column 17.

Answer (score 1):

I think, your database have number datatype for KEY_ID. then you can use cursor.getInt(0) instead of Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))

replace this line.

```
  StatutoryModel contact = new StatutoryModel(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8), cursor.getString(9), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(10)), cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(13)), cursor.getString(14), cursor.getString(15), cursor.getString(16), cursor.getString(17), cursor.getString(18), cursor.getString(19));
```

to

```
    StatutoryModel contact = new StatutoryModel(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8), cursor.getString(9), cursor.getInt(10), cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12), cursor.getInt(13), cursor.getString(14), cursor.getString(15), cursor.getString(16), cursor.getString(17), cursor.getString(18), cursor.getString(19));
```

I hope this will help you. thanks

Comment: Im getting Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 17 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: make sure close cursor properly.. use cursor.close(); before  return contact;

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this

Before you convert into integer first check it's not empty or not blank

**Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))**

Above statement when the cursor.getString(0) return int then no
issue but when return any string then give the number NumberFormatException.

so give proper validation before convert,
```

Comment: please formate your answer properly, so that it looks in a specific manner..!!

Answer (score 0):

String.valueOf() will not treat "" as a number this is the main reason you are getting this exception. you should pass 0 instead.

I would like to know How you are calling this method getStatutoryRow(). I think the method call is error prone.

Comment: Im getting `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 17 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.`

Comment: In line Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_KNOWLEDGE_STATUTORY, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                        KEY_STATUTORY_MAPPING, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_DESCRIPTION,KEY_ACTIVE,KEY_PROVISION,KEY_COMPLIANCE_TASK,KEY_FORMAT_FILE_LIST,KEY_DURATION,KEY_DOC_NAME,KEY_PENAL_CONSEQUENCE,KEY_DURATION_ID,KEY_FREQUENCY_ID,KEY_REPEAT_FREQ,KEY_COMPLIANCE_ID,KEY_REPEAT_TYPE_ID,KEY_STATUTORY_MONTH}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null); You are passing only 17 column names i.e 0-16 records in cursor. Find out the missing column names and pass it in parameter.